# Powers of the golden ratio

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Let $\phi$ be the golden ratio. I'm tasked to prove *by other means than induction* that $x$ in the next equation $$\phi^n =\phi F_n +x,$$ is actually a Fibonacci number.
I have tried to apply Binet's formula to $\phi^n -\phi F_n$:
\begin{align} \phi^n -\phi F_n &= \phi^n -\phi \left(\dfrac{\phi^n -\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^n}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\\ &=\phi^n -\frac{\phi^{n+1} -\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^n \phi}{\sqrt{5}}\\ &=\frac{\sqrt{5} \phi^n -\phi^{n+1} +\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^n \phi}{\sqrt{5}}. \end{align}
But then I got stuck. Could you please help me?

---

Comment: This is hard to read.  Do you mean $\phi^n=\phi \times F_n+F_k$?  If $\phi=\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2$ then how is  your claim true when $n=2$?

Comment: Sorry about that still learning. Yes everything you wrote above is correct. except I have to prove for a general case. So, eventually i should be able to find out that k = n-1.

Comment: Have you tried using induction on $n$?

Comment: @lulu, perhaps we're using $F_1=F_2=1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Right.  I worked that out (eventually).

Comment: @GerryMyerson@lulu I have sent a link to some working out i have tried to do

Comment: You can't ping two people in one comment.

Comment: And, why can't you use induction?

Comment: Yes, I was about to ask the same thing.  This seems like an obvious indiction problem.

Comment: Because for that you would have to assume that ϕn=ϕ×Fn+Fk+1. And yes i have proved it using induction. However, the question requires for a prove other than induction

Comment: Alright. Thankyou for your help

Comment: @lulu The question requires to prove ϕn=ϕFn+[Another Fibonacci number]. So, I was thinking could i prove that the [another Fibonacci number] is of the form Fn-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from $$\phi^n -\phi F_n,$$ then plug $$F_n \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (\phi^n -\varphi^n)$$ where $$\phi =\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \qquad \varphi =\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2},$$ and use properties of $\phi$ and $\varphi$, namely, that $$1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\varphi, \qquad \phi \varphi=-1,$$ to compute another Fibonacci number.

> $$\phi^n -\phi F_n =\phi^n -\phi \cdot \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\phi^n -\varphi^n) =\phi^n -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \phi^{n+1} +\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \phi \varphi^n \\ =\left(1-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \phi\right)\phi^n +\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi \varphi^n =-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \varphi \phi^n +\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \phi \varphi^n \\ =-\varphi \phi \cdot \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\phi^{n-1} -\varphi^{n-1} \right) =\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \phi^{n-1} -\varphi^{n-1} \right) =F_{n-1}.$$

Comment: I would like to prove that ϕn - ϕFn = Fn−1. Using, the LHS only. Would that still be possible without induction?

Comment: If you can prove the RHS is equal to the LHS, then by reversibility, the LHS is equal to the RHS. Or write the computations backwards.

Comment: Yes that is completely true. But in the question i have to assume that ϕn - ϕFn = [Another Fibonacci number]. And that [Another Fibonacci number] is not allowed to be assumed to be Fn−1. So, practcially the question states that find the general case for the value of [Another Fibonacci number] for ϕn - ϕFn = [Another Fibonacci number] to be satisfied. So i have to prove it assuming i only know the LHS part of the equation which is: ϕn - ϕFn

Comment: Oh, I see. I edited my answer accordingly. Same reasoning.

Comment: Alright! Thanks alot

Comment: Just a final question. Are there proofs for your identites which you have used. If so could you please tell me. Thanks alot

Comment: The numbers $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are the roots (positive and negative, respectively) of the equation $x^2-x-1=0$, and their properties are straight forward:
$$1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \phi =1 -\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}} =\frac{2\sqrt{5} -1-\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}} =\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\varphi, \\ \phi \varphi =\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) =\frac{1-5}{4} =-1.$$

Comment: The equivalence $$F_n \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (\phi^n -\varphi^n),$$ however, requieres to be proven differently, either by deriving it (with generating functions or considering the eigendecomposition of this matrix $A :=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ which is special because $$A^n =\begin{pmatrix} F_{n+1}&F_n\\ F_n&F_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$$ ) or by induction.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\phi F_n = \phi\frac{\phi^n - \bar{\phi}^n}{\phi - \bar{\phi}}
=\frac{\phi^{n+1} - \phi\bar{\phi}^n}{\phi - \bar{\phi}}
=\frac{\phi^{n+1} + \phi\bar{\phi}^{n-1}}{\phi - \bar{\phi}}
$$
$$
\phi F_n +F_k
=\frac{\phi^{n+1} + \phi\bar{\phi}^{n-1}+\phi^k - \bar{\phi}^k}{\phi - \bar{\phi}}
$$
and $ \phi F_n +F_k = \phi^n$ if and only if
$$
=\frac{\phi^{n+1} + \phi\bar{\phi}^{n-1}+\phi^k - \bar{\phi}^k}{\phi - \bar{\phi}} = \phi^n
$$
or
$$
\phi^{n+1} + \phi\bar{\phi}^{n-1}+\phi^k - \bar{\phi}^k = \phi^{n+1} - \phi^n\bar{\phi}= \phi^{n+1}+\phi^{n-1}
$$

Setting $k=n-1$ gives the result you desire.